# Neo4j intermittent ClassCastException while casting null to boolean

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to build a query which abort / throws error if a pattern is not match, meaning to stop executing query by condition

Here is the query:

```
1. MATCH (p:PERSON {name:'person-x'})
2. OPTIONAL MATCH (c:CITY {name:'dublin'})
3. OPTIONAL MATCH (cy:COUNTRY {name:'germany'})
4. OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[crcy:PART_OF]->(cy)
5. OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[plc:LIVES_IN]->(c)
6. WITH p,c, crcy ,cy,plc,
7.      CASE crcy IS NOT NULL
8.          WHEN true THEN true
9.          WHEN false THEN null
10.     END as validLocKey
11.     CALL apoc.do.when(validLocKey AND plc IS NOT NULL,
12.         'RETURN p, plc, c',
13.         'OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[plcTd:LIVES_IN]->(:CITY) DELETE plcTd MERGE (p)-[plcCr:LIVES_IN]->(c) RETURN p,plcCr,c',
14.     {p:p, plc:plc, c:c}) YIELD value
15. RETURN p,plc,value.plcCr ,c, crcy ,cy
```

where the positive case works fine.
But, when replacing line:2 with `OPTIONAL MATCH (c:CITY {name:'dublin'})` which would eventually not match any pattern (*as dublin is not under germany in DB meta*) in line:4 and thus `crcy` is null.

line:7 is false

line:9 returns null, which should throw error from line:11 (null cast to boolean exception)

line:11 check on two conditions with AND operator

So, i thought of this approach to catch the error and handle it as invalid data.
But, the error is not throwing at first attempt, it first creates pattern in db `person-LIVES_IN->dublin` which is not expected as the `"country":"germany"` from RequestBody is invalid request. Only on the second try, it throws as below:

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.do.when`: Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.neo4j.values.storable.NoValue
> cannot be cast to class org.neo4j.values.storable.BooleanValue
> (org.neo4j.values.storable.NoValue and
> org.neo4j.values.storable.BooleanValue are in unnamed module of loader
> 'app')

Not sure why the error is not popping at first attempt. Is there any other way to get the desired result by modifying the query? Please correct me if i'm wrong!

Note: used Neo4j browser

**valid data:**

```
{
  "person": "person-x",
  "city": "frankfurt",
  "country": "germany"
}
```

**invalid data:**

```
{
  "person": "person-x",
  "city": "dublin",
  "country": "germany"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the above-mentioned behavior because of how neo4j evaluates `null` values in a Boolean Expression. In the case of an `AND` operation, like `a AND b`, if `a` is `null` and `b` is `false`, then the expression results in `false`, and if `a` is `null` and `b` is `true`, then the expression results in `null`. Here's the link to the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/working-with-null/), containing the truth table for `null` values.

In your case, the expression `validLocKey AND plc IS NOT NULL`, evaluates to `false` in the first run because `validLocKey` is `null` and `plc` is `null` as well, so the statement becomes `null AND false` which is `false`. On the second run, `validLocKey` is `null`, but now `plc` is not `null`, so the statement becomes `null AND true`, which results in `null`, and you get the above mentioned exception, since, `null` can't be evaluated as a `boolean`

So the way to fix this is basically, instead of relying on the exception to handle invalid data, return appropriate `booleans` from query response and use them to handle the inappropriate data. Something like this:

```
MATCH (p:PERSON {name:'person-x'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:CITY {name:'dublin'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (cy:COUNTRY {name:'germany'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[crcy:PART_OF]->(cy)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[plc:LIVES_IN]->(c)
WITH p,c, crcy ,cy,plc, crcy IS NOT NULL as validLocKey
     // Create the relationship only if the location is valid and plc is Null
     CALL apoc.do.when(validLocKey AND plc IS NULL,
         'OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[plcTd:LIVES_IN]->(:CITY) DELETE plcTd MERGE (p)-[plcCr:LIVES_IN]->(c) RETURN p,plcCr,c',
         'RETURN p, plc, c',
     {p:p, plc:plc, c:c}) YIELD value
 RETURN p,plc,value.plcCr ,c, crcy ,cy, validLocKey
```

Please modify the query accordingly, as per the expected behavior. Hopefully, it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the truth table reference. But from the suggested query the else part would return empty values. but, i need to prompt the user by an message that this pattern 'validLocKey' is invalid combination. Will post my finding as another answer. Thanks for your explanation though.

Comment: Tha above query will return `false` as the value of `validLocKey` when the combination is invalid. That can be used to prompt the user. However, feel free to modify according to your use-case